# Jquery treeview collapse except of root

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I used [JQuery TreeView](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/demo/index.html) in large mode I want to collapse all items **except of root** how I can change jquery.treeview.js to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well..not the cleanest solution maybe, but seems to work:

```
$("#navigation").treeview({collapsed:true}).find('div.hitarea:first').click();
```

greez
ay

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following, it must work:

```
$("#navigation").treeview({
  collapsed: true,
  unique: true,
  "expanded": true,
  persist: "location"
})
.find('div.hitarea:first')
.click();
```