# Jquery Tree Collapsed State

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a jQuery easyui tree inside a JQuery accordion. By default, the tree structure is uncollapsed. All subfolders are visible, but I need the whole thing to be collapsed, starting at the root. My sample code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./easyui/themes/icon.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navigation").treeview({
    animated: "fast",
    collapsed: true,
    control: "#treecontrol"
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Tree TestTest</h3>
  <div title="Tree Menu">
    <ul id="navigation" class="easyui-tree">
        <li>
            <span>Folder1</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Sub Folder 1</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>File 11</span></li>
                        <li><span>File 12</span></li>
                        <li><span>File 13</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>File 2</span></li>
                <li><span>File 3</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>File2</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have consulted this stack overflow post:

[Jquery treeview collapse except of root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711174/jquery-treeview-collapse-except-of-root)

And that's where I got the idea of the script in the head. However it will not collapse. In my actual file, the accordion is in an external file that is used on each page using `include`. I have tried using the script in both the included file and the actual page and nothing works. Please help me close this tree! Thank you all very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had trouble getting `collapsed: true` to work.  Instead, try adding `data-options="state:'closed'"` to your `<li>` tag.  So if you wanted to make "Folder1" initially collapsed, it would look like this:

`<div title="Tree Menu">
  <ul id="navigation" class="easyui-tree">
    <li data-options="state:'closed'">
      <span>Folder1</span>`

This doesn't apply to child nodes, so you will have to do it for each tree node that you want collapsed.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Sorry for the delay, it's been a while since I've been able to get back on SO. Thanks a lot!